# Strtr requires an array as the second argument?

Tags: php, string, strtr

I am calling code like

```
strtr($somevars['thisvar'], "abc")
```

Where `$somevars['thisvar']` contains a string.

And it's giving me

```
Warning:  strtr() [function.strtr]: The second argument is not an array
```

Why?

Comment: The warning is about `strtr`, not `strstr`

Comment: It's a typo, i ment to write `strstr` in my code. The question is basically over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Warning:  strtr() [function.strtr]: The second argument is not an array

strtr != str**s**tr

see: http://docs.php.net/strtr

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilties for [strtr](http://php.net/strtr):

```
string strtr ( string $str , string $from , string $to );

string strtr ( string $str , array $replace_pairs );
```

So even you add a third parameters and you can use a string, or you set an array and don't add a third parameter :)